# Upload suddenly failing from WP Bakery Single Image Block

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, plupload

I am having an issue regarding uploading an image from WP Bakery's Single Image Block Upload.

- When I upload from the library, Wordpress selects properly the image and the image in the Bakery's Visual editing is properly updated.
- When I load a new image from my computer ( Select a file and upload ) I get an "**Error loading. Please try again**" message.

**Steps taken to track this issue**

Upon inspection of the request made to WP's **wp-admin/async_upload.php**, on Chrome, I get this response:

```
{"success":false,"data":{"message":"","filename":"food-2373414_1920.jpg"}}
```

I attempted to track the issue in **wp-admin/ajax-actions.php**, and the error first occurs around line 2561 which has the following snippet:

```
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'async-upload', $post_id, $post_data );    

if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
    echo wp_json_encode(
        array(
            'success' => false,
            'data'    => array(
                'message'  => $attachment_id->get_error_message(),
                'filename' => esc_html( $_FILES['async-upload']['name'] ),
            ),
        )
    );

    wp_die();
}
```

Note: I say **first occurs** because the request dies and can't follow up in the next lines. So, at this time, the block above is the first obstacle.

Dumping $attachment_id

```
WP_Error::__set_state(array(
   'errors' => 
  array (
    'upload_error' => 
    array (
      0 => '',
    ),
  ),
   'error_data' => 
  array (
  ),
))
```

**Configurations and Environment**

PHP 7.2 w/ Mod Security disabled from Cpanel, w/ GD & Imagick

Server Apache

0777 Permissions at uploads folder

**Wordpress Settings :**

WP Version: 5.4.1

URL and Site URL's both start with https://

User is Administrator

Theme: [Business Consulting](https://themeforest.net/item/advice-consulting-business-theme/20143325/comments)

**Other information researched and findings:**

- On a test server, the upload works as expected. From the environment and wordpress settings everything, except for ModSec ( which in the test server does not exist in the Cpanel ). I have also found out that by disabling a plugin ( Real Simple SSL and SSL Insecure Fixer ) and logout and login again, the issue seemed to take care of itself, but I have tried the same in the production server and doesn't work.
- Mostly errors from this nature only relate to a HTTP Error occuring. Even trying to use the fixes stated in some sites ( permissions, changing Imagick to GD as the image processing library, giving more memory, max_upload_file_size, max_execution_time, max_input_vars, does not seem to fix this issue.
- Opening the website in a Private Tab does not work, as well as opening in Firefox.

**Other possible causes :**

I edit Wordpress content in https://.

Every listing's pages, does not show the Mixed Content warnings, but when I edit a give article from the theme, there a lot's of MC warnings. That does not seem to hinder the upload, but for now I will leave them as it is. The request to async_upload is made via SSL, so I don't think the MC's are the cause. But for Murphy's Law sake, I will replace the http:// to https:// and try again.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

The problem is that, when I changed the slugs from on of the Advice theme's sections ( adv_cases to adv_portfolio ), the upload from articles that were previously registered before this changed were not working.

I solved it by duplicating or creating a new post, and voilá, the upload works.